# Problem when I assign a variable to ssh2_sftp($connection)

Tags: php, ssh2

I'm trying to use ssh2_sftp($connection) but if i assign variable like that

`$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection)`

My serveur return error 503

But if i do print_r(ssh2_sftp($connection)) i've ressource :

`Resource id #137`

The problem is for the rest of the code i can't do that :

`$stream = fopen("ssh2.sftp://$sftp/path/to/file", 'r');`

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am facing exactly the same behavior, the strange thing is that if  I fopen the file on "w" mode the file is created(if it does not exist) but still I get a 503 error. I even try the "intval($sftp)" solution than I found on similar posts but still nothing.